# Does Spark AR support transparent videos?

Tags: augmented-reality, spark-ar-studio

So the question is does Spark AR support transparent videos?  I've tried to play QuickTime's mov format, but nothing's displayed.

Comment: You may need to upload the alpha channel as a separate video texture.

Answer (score 2):

Spark doesn't support video unfortunately. The easiest thing might be to instead import the video as a sequence of PNGs with an alpha channel, and play that sequence as a "2D texture animation".

https://sparkar.facebook.com/ar-studio/learn/documentation/building-your-scene/animation-and-interactivity/2D-texture-animation/